# Log in and download - Python Requests

Tags: python, authentication, web-scraping, python-requests

I've been trying to login on this website and download some files for a while now. I can't find out what is wrong with my code below. I'm new to Python:

When you hit the login page https://www.targetsite/members/login.php, it makes the following calls:

Login page:

```
[General]
Request URL: https://www.targetsite/members/login.php
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 302 Found
Remote Address: 0.0.0.0:443
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade

[Response Headers]
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 425
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
Date: Thu, 13 Dec 2018 14:37:02 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=5
Location: https://www.targetsite/auth.form?bWFmYkpTbjhNN0J4bWM2S2NwaCtlNTkydDJJV0xiMk1aTWRKa0kwVldWZ29hZjdaMEUweFJuRWl3a3NqOVUwTwpSbmtyRnptekp6Wm40VlM2MDF5dWVVSDR2V1FXMG5JU1ZNQVUrZ0lvYTlXTWQ4T2ZEVzJVY1ZSWW4wZk1NVHZhCm9uZWZZeTI2V1JNPQo=
Server: nginx/1.14.2
Set-Cookie: pcar%5fUkVTVFJJQ1RFRA%3d%3d=; path=/; domain=.targetsite; expires=Wed 13-Dec-2017 14:37:02 GMT
X-Vegas-No-Cache: YES

[Request Headers]
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Connection: keep-alive
Cookie: pcah=SXlOK1VkSytiMTl0VllvbDk4N2tVaXR5bmZFZmNNVUsK
Host: www.targetsite
Referer: http://www.targetsite/tour/index.php
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.77 Safari/537.36 Vivaldi/2.1.1337.36
```

AuthForm:

```
[General]
Request URL: https://www.targetsite/auth.form?bWFmYkpTbjhNN0J4bWM2S2NwaCtlNTkydDJJV0xiMk1aTWRKa0kwVldWZ29hZjdaMEUweFJuRWl3a3NqOVUwTwpSbmtyRnptekp6Wm40VlM2MDF5dWVVSDR2V1FXMG5JU1ZNQVUrZ0lvYTlXTWQ4T2ZEVzJVY1ZSWW4wZk1NVHZhCm9uZWZZeTI2V1JNPQo=
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 200 OK
Remote Address: 0.0.0.0:443
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade

[Response Headers]
Cache-Control: max-age=1, must-revalidate
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: text/html
Date: Thu, 13 Dec 2018 14:37:03 GMT
Expires: Thu, 13 Dec 2018 14:37:03 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=5
Server: nginx/1.14.2
Set-Cookie: pcar%5fUkVTVFJJQ1RFRA%3d%3d=; path=/; domain=.targetsite; expires=Wed 13-Dec-2017 14:37:03 GMT
Transfer-Encoding: chunked

[Request Headers]
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Connection: keep-alive
Cookie: pcah=SXlOK1VkSytiMTl0VllvbDk4N2tVaXR5bmZFZmNNVUsK
Host: www.targetsite
Referer: http://www.targetsite/tour/index.php
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.77 Safari/537.36 Vivaldi/2.1.1337.36
bWFmYkpTbjhNN0J4bWM2S2NwaCtlNTkydDJJV0xiMk1aTWRKa0kwVldWZ29hZjdaMEUweFJuRWl3a3NqOVUwTwpSbmtyRnptekp6Wm40VlM2MDF5dWVVSDR2V1FXMG5JU1ZNQVUrZ0lvYTlXTWQ4T2ZEVzJVY1ZSWW4wZk1NVHZhCm9uZWZZeTI2V1JNPQo:
```

So based on that behaviour observed using chrome inspector, I coded the following, trying to emulate the actions triggered after accessing https://www.targetsite.com/members/login.php

```
#Libraries
import requests
import json
from lxml import html

#URL
primeiraUrl = 'https://www.targetsite.com/members/login.php'
urlPost = 'https://ams.targetsite.com/auth.form'

#Credentials
userd = 'user'
passwd = 'pass'

session = requests.Session()
#session.verify = False

#GetToken

headers = {
        'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8',
        'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
        'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
        'Connection': 'keep-alive',
        'Referer': 'http://www.targetsite.com/tour/index.php',
        'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.77 Safari/537.36 Vivaldi/2.1.1337.36'
}


get1stContact = session.get(primeiraUrl,headers=headers)
segundaUrl = get1stContact.url

get2ndContact = session.get(segundaUrl,headers=headers)
```

And then when you login on the website, that's what you get:

```
[General]
Request URL: https://ams.targetsite.com/auth.form
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 302 Found
Remote Address: 1.1.1.1:443
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade

[Response Headers]
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 239
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
Date: Thu, 13 Dec 2018 14:47:57 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=20, max=94
Location: http://www.targetsite.com/members/index.php
Server: Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS)
Set-Cookie: pcar%5fUkVTVFJJQ1RFRA%3d%3d=cS90NW9XLzVVeVNIeElMOUpFaHlCb2hGWkZveVUrdTFiK0dad0FYVDN2UT0K; path=/; domain=.targetsite.com; expires=Thu 13-Dec-2018 20:47:57 GMT

[Request Headers]
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 147
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Cookie: pcah=Q3BLRnpDUGRhcnJFMmg1OGI0LzBrLzNhYWM5cjBVV2IK
Host: ams.targetsite.com
Origin: https://www.targetsite.com
Referer: https://www.targetsite.com/auth.form?N2dFMUIwaGFIc1BWQ3BoRTd2NVBWayt5ZE91UnZsa2xCcmNUU1VtVG8yNW54WUhjNFBYblE3STJwK2xrRWhNawpNRWtmMjJtUFF2Y0xSL2t1N2xIc2pmSk4wZG5uRVdmbkEyRUpxdnVDODI4UmVhMjlId1h6dVZIeFRtWGZuUGd5CkoySHEwZXg5RnRVPQo=
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.77 Safari/537.36 Vivaldi/2.1.1337.36

[Form-Data]
rlm: RESTRICTED
for: http%3a%2f%2fwww%2etargetsite%2ecom%2fmembers%2findex%2ephp
rmb: y
uid: user
pwd: pass
```

And here is the code I wrote to make that post request:

```
headers = {
            'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8',
            'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
            'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
            'Cache-Control': 'max-age=0',
            'Connection': 'keep-alive',
            'Origin': 'https://www.targetsite.com',
            'Referer': segundaUrl,
            'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
            'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.77 Safari/537.36 Vivaldi/2.1.1337.36'
        }


body = {
        'rlm':'RESTRICTED',
        'for':'http://www.targetsite.com/members/index.php',
        'rmb': 'y',
        'uid': 'user',
        'pwd': 'pass'
}


#session.post(url)
r = session.post(urlPost, headers=headers, data=body)
```

That all being said there's anyone who can help me figure this out ? Thanks in advance!

Edit.: Full code as requested:

```
#Help
#http://kazuar.github.io/scraping-tutorial/

#Libraries
import requests
import json
from lxml import html

#URL
primeiraUrl = 'https://www.targetsite.com/members/login.php'
urlPost = 'https://ams.targetsite.com/auth.form'

#Credentials
userd = 'user'
passwd = 'pass'

session = requests.Session()
#session.verify = False

#GetToken

headers = {
        'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8',
        'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
        'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
        'Connection': 'keep-alive',
        'Referer': 'http://www.targetsite.com/tour/index.php',
        'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.77 Safari/537.36 Vivaldi/2.1.1337.36'
}


get1stContact = session.get(primeiraUrl,headers=headers)
segundaUrl = get1stContact.url

get2ndContact = session.get(segundaUrl,headers=headers)




headers = {
            'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8',
            'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
            'Cache-Control': 'max-age=0',
            'Connection': 'keep-alive',
            'Origin': 'https://www.targetsite.com',
            'Referer': segundaUrl,
            'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
            'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.77 Safari/537.36 Vivaldi/2.1.1337.36'
        }


body = {
        'rlm':'RESTRICTED',
        'for':'http://www.targetsite.com/members/index.php',
        'rmb': 'y',
        'uid': 'user',
        'pwd': 'pass'
}





#session.post(url)
r = session.post(urlPost, headers=headers, data=body)
print(r.text)
```

Comment: for sure, done as you requested.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing to send some headers, most importantly:

```
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

That one is very important, as it tells the server how to parse the parameters you are sending in your form.

Comment: Hi thanks for that! I tried but still no luck, it redirects me back to the login page.